# React with NextJS and Next-CSS: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, next.js

To building a React-App i using NextJS. To use a css-file, i use the `next-css plugin` to do that. But when i build my App, i get the following error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

My `next.config.js` file, looks like this:

```
// next.config.js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS({
  cssModules: false,
})
```

I importe and use a .css-file in my components as follows:

```
import '../style.css'
export default () => <div className="example">Hello World!</div>
```

My css-file Looks like this:

```
.example {
  color: red;
 }
```

Where is my issue? Can anyone help me to fix that?

Comment: can you please add your CSS file content?

Comment: @yuyokk thanks for your answer... It doesn't matter what CSS rules I post there. The error always appears on

Answer (score 19):

I solved the problem. In my `next.config.js` i use multiple plugins. My mistake was that I had written several `module.exports` statements. In my case, the solution looks like this:

```
//next.config.js
const withImages = require('next-images');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withImages(withCSS());
```

Comment: I can confirm, that this works with version 9 of next.js

Comment: Adding this one plugin does work. Confirmed. Next 9.1.1

Comment: This worked for me for adding CSS and SASS together like; `withCSS(withSass())`

Answer (score 7):

**Try this in your next.config.js:**

```
// next.config.js 
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')

module.exports = withCSS({
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    url: false
  }
})
```

Now you should be able to import styleshets from node_modules like this:

```
import 'bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

*Note: Using Next v 8+*

**Background:**
I spent a few hours trying to simply import a CSS installed as a node_module and the various solutions are mostly hacky workarounds, but as shown above, there is a simple solution.
It was provided by one of the core team members: https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/ignoring-folders-files-specifically-fonts~4f68cfd5-d576-46b8-adc8-86e9d7ea0b1f

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what problem you have but I just followed the [docs example](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css):

1 Installed next-css `npm install --save @zeit/next-css`

2 Created `next.config.js`

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
module.exports = withCSS();
```

3 Created `style.css` file in the root folder

```
.example {
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

4 Created a test page that includes styles

```
import '../style.css';

export default () => <div className="example">Hello World!</div>;
```

and the result shows [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/09bakcp7cxo7exy/Screenshot%202018-09-27%2022.47.13.png?dl=0)

I have the following dependencies

```
"@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
"next": "^7.0.0",
"react": "^16.5.2",
"react-dom": "^16.5.2"
```

Hope this helps you a bit!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you show me your structure for this app once? Maybe it's my fault.

Comment: sure, here it is https://github.com/yuyokk/nextjs-css-basic-usage-example/

Comment: Any ideas on how to use this including also additional Next configs?

Comment: @AmyPellegrini what configs you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: I've noticed there are many plugins to extend the config using currying patterns, but sometimes the syntax or pattern to follow is not straight forward usable, for example, I'm working on a project where we use `withCSS`, `withPlugins`, `withConfig` functions (imported from `@zeit/next-css` and similar plugins), but I had to spend some time to make them work in combination. Anyway, it's sorted out now! But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time but maybe it will help someone.
I was having the same problem while adding video in Nextjs.

First you should install file-loader

```
npm i file-loader
```

Then I have changed my next.config.js file like;

```
module.exports = {
webpack: (config) => {
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(mov|mp4|webm)$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: "file-loader",
      options: {
        publicPath: "/_next/static/videos/",
        outputPath: "static/videos/",
        name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
        esModule: false,
      },
    },
  ],
});

return config;
},
};
```

These steps fixed my problem.

Comment: it works for a while but suddently stop working for whatever reason, now i use next-videos module and still working